# What is Snowbird flapping mechanism?

Tags: flight-mechanics, airframe-and-powerplant, ornithopters

Reading [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67948/are-exoskeleton-wings-technically-possible) and the great answer to it talking about Snowbird sustained human powered flight visible [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0E77j1imdhQ),

I was wondering and still cannot find nor figure out how power is converted from rowingbike to this smooth graceful flapping motion. What does this transmission look like?

Comment: Ok my bad, if I watched the video until the very end I would have seen the ornithopter.ca watermark, where everything is, if not explained in detail, at least very understandable. Still, any further technical details are welcome.

Comment: Watching other ornithopter videos may help.  I have wondered if bird "flapping" was an optical illusion, with the wings actually moving in a more circular motion.  An interesting frame of reference thought.  Small scale ornithopters fly well.  One design allows the outer wing to fold on the upstroke and open on the downstroke.